# Spark-submit causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on standalone mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am testing my spark application locally, with standalone mode, packing everything into uber jar. At some point I updated dependency library to a new version, and spark-submit now causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError,and this method exists in new version and not in previous.

I cleaned local maven repo, but that did not help.

It still works in --master local[1], but not --master local[2], or --master local[*]

What is wrong? Uber jar should prevent such things, should not it?

UPD.
code where it fails (addAll method)
`   def union(first: Array[Byte], second: Array[Byte]) = {
      val bf1 = BloomFilter.deserialize(first)
      val bf2 = BloomFilter.deserialize(second)
      bf1.addAll(bf2)
      BloomFilter.serialize(bf1)
    }

```
val bytes = rdd.mapPartitions(it => {
  val bf = new BloomFilter(expectedElements.toInt, falsePositiveRate)
  for (element <- it.map(_.getAs[String](onField)).filter(_ != null)){
    bf.add(element)
  }
  BloomFilter.serialize(bf)
  Iterator(BloomFilter.serialize(bf))}
).reduce(union)`
```

and the lib is
com.clearspring.analytics:stream:2.9.5

I did not remember the exact previous version I used, but there was no addAll method.

Comment: Could you provide the code snippet where it fails and also your dependency file.

Comment: What you mean with It still works in --master local[1] ? With new lib uber jar ?

Comment: yes, it works with local[1], and does not with local[*]

Comment: try build '3.0' version from https://github.com/addthis/stream-lib/tree/v3.0.0

Comment: No, this method exists in current version i am using, it looks like previous version was cached somewhere(that is weird to me).